# chrome extension blocking google.co.uk

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have a simple unpacked chrome extension loaded. All other extensions turned off.

manifest.js

```
{
  "manifest_version":2,
  "name":"Etc",
  "description":"Etc",
  "version":"1.0",
  "content_scripts": [{
      "matches" : ["*://*/*"],
      "js": ["contentscript.js"],
      "run_at":"document_end"
  }],
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["background.js"],
    "persistent": false
  },
  "permissions":[
    "tabs", 
    "*://*/*"
  ],
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "Idonethis", 
    "default_icon":"icon.png"
  }
}
```

The background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.greeting == "hello")
      sendResponse({farewell: "goodbye"});
});
```

The contentscript.js

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({greeting:"hello"}, function(response) {
  console.log(response.farewell);
});
```

On most domains such as www.bbc.co.uk the message passing works correctly and displays

```
message contentscript.js:2
```

However on www.google.co.uk or uk.yahoo.com it does not pass a message, nor execute any contentscript.js as far as I can tell. Is this part of the security specification of chrome extensions?

EDIT
This code has been fixed and can be viewed here
https://github.com/lindaymacvean/test-chrome-ext

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably because of the match rule `"matches" : ["*://*/"]`. You need to change it to `"matches" : ["*://*/*"]` because currently it only matches tabs that have no path on them. E.g. `http://example.com/` will match but `http://example.co.uk/foo` will not match.

Comment: I have fixed it and it works thank you. For anyone else that looks at this question I have left a git-repo so you can copy the boilerplate code.